# Delete cosmos document with unique keys without fetching object first

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, http-delete

my object look like this:

```
{
  "documentType":"doc",
  "relatedKey": "Person1",
  "Color": "blue",
  "Street": "SomeStreet",
}
```

**Partition key** is set to /documentType

**UniqueKey** is set to /documentType,/relatedKey

Now how can I delete a document directly by sending in the Partition key and **UniqueKey**?? by using the Cosmos API??

Here is some code to show what I am trying to achieve:

```
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("{documentType}/{relatedKey}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> DeleteDocument(string documentType, string relatedKey)
    {
        Document doc = await documentClient.DeleteDocumentAsync(String.Format("/dbs/{0}/colls/{1}/docs/{2}/{3}", database, collection, documentType, relatedKey), new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKey(documentType) });
        return Ok("ExtensionDocument deleted");
    }
```

My main difficulty is to delete an object with multiple unique keys and not only the PartitionKey

With only a PartitionKey I know how to delete a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete a document this way. You must use the doc id and the partition key.

Docs on Delete are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/delete-a-document)

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid of that

Comment: Is this still the case as of now?

Comment: Yes, this is never going to change. Unique keys cannot be used to filter for data, it is a constraint for data on insert and update. You must always use the pk and id. The pk tells Cosmos what partition the data sits on. The id is a unique value within a logical partition that tells the service the value to be deleted.